# Periodically execute python function

Tags: python, scheduler

How can I set a python function to run at 0:00 am every Monday? I studied several python scheduler package like APScheduler but it turns out it is hard to run the funcion with parameters.

Comment: If you are on a *nix system, use a cron. If you are on a Windows machine, use Windows Scheduler.

Comment: Use Cron or schtasks

Answer (score 1):

Are you on linux? Add a cron job using

```
crontab -e
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: Yes, on Ubuntu. What I want is to call a python function in the other running python program periodically, like every Monday morning.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, I don't see why you would ever need to do this.

Comment: If you use a cron job, you can restart the program/run a new one every monday morning